# variable name "weight" is conflicting the WCF in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: c#, wsdl

I am trying to connect my vendor's WSDL service with Visual Studio 2022 Service Reference function.

However I found that one of the parameter "weight" had always been disappeared in the outgoing XML.

Here is the generated weight field:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=7)]
    public int weight
    {
        get
        {
            return this.weightField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.weightField = value;
        }
    }
```

I tried to rename "weight" to "Weight" or "gWeight", the field can be outputted in the outgoing XML without any problem.
What could be the possible reason?

Comment: Use the new keyword in the derived class to hide the base class method. Example: public new int weight { // your code}